# What are untrusted constraints and what action needs taken to rectify?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-migration-assistant

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-bestpractices?view=sql-server-ver15

> Check for untrusted constraints on both the source database and the
> target database before migrating data.

What are untrusted constraints? And what does check for untrusted constrains mean? Check specifically what and what action is to be taken?

Answer (score 1):

A foreign key that was created or updated using WITH NOCHECK. Basically, the data in the tables isn't validated, so there's no way of knowing if the data is accurate to the constraint or not. [Here's more info on it](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=e3fa8392df85137c88a810a55aabc8c9e4892f5170d182c55e02c2e7dd5b94d1JmltdHM9MTY0OTg1NTM2NiZpZ3VpZD04NDc4MjZhYi02NjQ3LTRlOTEtOWFlNy01NDdlNzZhYWVmZjImaW5zaWQ9NTE2OQ&ptn=3&fclid=f1f3dacb-bb2a-11ec-b2bd-8a808285d739&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly9kYXRhYmFzZS5ndWlkZS93aGF0LXlvdS1zaG91bGQta25vdy1hYm91dC13aXRoLW5vY2hlY2std2hlbi1lbmFibGluZy1hLWNoZWNrLWNvbnN0cmFpbnQtaW4tc3FsLXNlcnZlci8_bXNjbGtpZD1mMWYzZGFjYmJiMmExMWVjYjJiZDhhODA4Mjg1ZDczOQ&ntb=1).

Comment: So `with nocheck` allows to bypass the check constrain. But what is the reason untrusted constraints are problem?

Comment: The optimizer completely depends on knowing that the data in a foreign key constraint is enforced. If not, you're more likely to see problematic plans. That's not to mention that your data could easily be just wrong. That one bothers me more than the optimizer thing.

Comment: You mean the data output of a select query can be wrong?

Comment: Sure. If the data constraint is not actually enforced, how can you be sure the data is accurate?

Comment: For example - you mean a select query with a join on the invalid foreign key value will result in that row missing in the output.

Comment: Yes, or you may get errors. Both.

Answer (score 1):

Say that you have a `CHECK` constraint that specifies that the "age" column in your table must be between 0 and 130.

Now, say that you disable that constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable NOCHECK CONSTRAINT myconstraint
```

You now have a disabled constraint. Say that you later re-enable that constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable CHECK CONSTRAINT myconstraint
```

That constraint is now enabled, but you can have data in there that was added while the constraint was disabled. I.e., the constraint isn't trusted. For instance, the optimizer cannot rely on that constraint for optimization. If you enabled it like below, however, then it wouldn't be untrusted:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable WITH CHECK CHECK myconstraint
```

The two types of constraint that might be untrusted are `CHECK` and `FOREIGN KEY` constraint.

Comment: Regarding foreign key - you mean foreign key constraint is disabled and a new row is added where-in the value of the foreign key is a non-existing value (null or non-existent primary key)? and later the foreign key constraint is enabled.

Comment: Yes, if the FK wasn't enabled using WITH CHECK, then the FK isn't trusted.

Comment: So why would this cause any issue with the DMA tool because the tool does a migration based on full backup/restore. What do you think?

Comment: We can only speculate. These tools tries to catch the most strange things sometimes. It is the same with the copy database wizard, where it suggest to carry over used-defined error messages. I mean, who create user-defined error messages (sp_addmessage)? Nobody, pretty much. Somebody just thought it would be a good idea to catch there things, that is the only speculation I can offer...

Comment: User defined error msgs are those `from sys.messages where message_id > 50000` -right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, this refers to constraints which have the option `WITH NOCHECK` set. This applies to foreign key constraints and check constraints.

You can find them using this query

```sql
SELECT
  s.name schema_name,
  t.name table_name,
  k.name constraint_name
FROM (
    SELECT 
      name,
      parent_object_id
    FROM sys.check_constraints
    WHERE is_not_trusted = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
      name,
      parent_object_id
    FROM sys.foreign_keys
    WHERE is_not_trusted = 1
) k
JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = k.parent_object_id
JOIN sys.schemas S ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id;
```

You can automatically set all constraints to `WITH CHECK` using this script

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) =
(
SELECT
  STRING_AGG(CAST('ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + ' WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;' AS nvarchar(max)), '
'    )
FROM (
    SELECT
      parent_object_id
    FROM sys.check_constraints
    WHERE is_not_trusted = 1
    UNION  -- do use not ALL
    SELECT 
      parent_object_id
    FROM sys.foreign_keys
    WHERE is_not_trusted = 1
) k
JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = k.parent_object_id
JOIN sys.schemas S ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server have a special feature on FOREIGN KEY and CHECK constraint that is called untrusted, that apply for the past data not for the incoming data...

Why ?

It is not usual like someone say that this special constraint status is applied when creatings tables. Mostly this appear when using BULK INSERT or BCP.exe, that disable FK and CHECK to faster inserts data into the table. Then this status remains at the table level, until you reset it a "trusted".

The trusted mode is very important because the optimizer use constraints to simplify query execution plan. Wen a constraint is not trusted, the optimizer will not use the constraint to find the optimal execution plan at the heuristic level...